# IOException when starting JBoss 5.1 GA

Tags: jboss, startup, ioexception

Starting my JBoss instance takes quite a while (11 minutes) on my server, and I think it is because of this error:

```
2012-07-19 09:37:46,546 INFO  [org.jboss.web.WebService] (main) Using RMI server codebase: http://zpssis1p:8083/
2012-07-19 09:38:14,143 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.NativeServerConfig] (main) JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
2012-07-19 09:38:14,145 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.NativeServerConfig] (main) 3.1.2.GA
2012-07-19 09:38:18,608 INFO  [org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AttributeCallbackItem] (main) Owner callback not implemented.
2012-07-19 09:38:26,204 INFO  [org.jboss.logbridge.LogNotificationListener] (main) Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@d2b64e[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
2012-07-19 09:39:25,721 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] (main) Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@13533447{vfsfile:/opt/jboss/5.1.0/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
2012-07-19 09:39:25,725 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] (main) Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@13533447{vfsfile:/opt/jboss/5.1.0/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
2012-07-19 09:39:25,725 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] (main) Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@13533447{vfsfile:/opt/jboss/5.1.0/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
2012-07-19 09:39:25,726 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] (main) Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@13533447{vfsfile:/opt/jboss/5.1.0/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
2012-07-19 09:47:03,479 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Start: name=jboss.remoting:protocol=rmi,service=JMXConnectorServer state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed

java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://zpssis1p:1090/jmxconnector]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: zpssis1p; nested exception is:
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:804)
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:417)
      at org.jboss.mx.remoting.service.JMXConnectorServerService.start(JMXConnectorServerService.java:131)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
      at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
      at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
      at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
      at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
      at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
      at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: zpssis1p; nested exception is:
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]
      at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:126)
      at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:208)
      at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:625)
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:412)
      ... 63 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: zpssis1p; nested exception is:
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
      at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
      at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:120)
      ... 67 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
      at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
      at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)
      at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
      at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
      ... 72 more
2012-07-19 09:04:11,331 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/opt/jboss/5.1.0/server/default/deploy/jmx-remoting.sar/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: jboss.remoting:service=JMXConnectorServer,protocol=rmi
      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:118)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
      at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
      at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
      at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://zpssis1p:1090/jmxconnector]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: zpssis1p; nested exception is:
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:804)
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:417)
      at org.jboss.mx.remoting.service.JMXConnectorServerService.start(JMXConnectorServerService.java:131)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
      at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
      at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
      at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
      at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
      ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: zpssis1p; nested exception is:
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]
      at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:126)
      at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:208)
      at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:625)
      at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:412)
      ... 63 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: zpssis1p; nested exception is:
      java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
      at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
      at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:120)
      ... 67 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
      at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
      at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)
      at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
      at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
      at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
      ... 72 more
```

Comment: Did you try  *netstat -a | grep 1090*  ?   Do you have iptables or some other firewall running ?

Comment: it says ` *.1090  *.*   0   0 49152  0 LISTEN` - firewall or iptables are running for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The file `/etc/hosts` contained the IP-address to the Apache server, that is installed in front of my JBoss server. I changed it to the correct IP-Adress, and the server can now connect on this port, and JBoss boots 3 minutes faster.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps:

1. Stop iptables if it running with  *`service iptables stop`* or  *`/etc/init.d/iptables stop`*.  (If the issue is iptables, you can later open the the specific port with a rule.)
2. Make sure there are no port conflicts with other servers running by mistake. 
   *`ps -ef | grep java`*   will tell you if there are other Java servers/processes running. 
   Make sure these processes are killed.  *`kill -9  <PID>`*  or *`killall -9 java`*.
3. Try again running Jboss.